# How to write an IF formular or multiple conditions in an Excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to use IF where you have Cell J188:J655 has either Yes or No but I want the formular to return YES on the ''No"just after each YES not all the ''NO".

Thank you.

```
3157802 SP  N
3157801 SP  N
3157800 SP  N
3157799 SP  N
3157798 SP  N
3157796 SP  N
3157797 SP  N
3157795 SP  N
3157794 SP  N
3157791 SP  N
3157790 SP  Y
3157789 SP  N
3157787 SP  N
3157788 SP  Y
3157786 SP  N
3157784 SP  N
3157785 SP  N
3157783 SP  N
3157779 CB  Y
3157782 D1  N
```

Comment: It might help if you would mock up some data and expected outcome.

Comment: Trying to post a picture but the side does not allow me to.

Comment: post the data as text, highlight the area and hit ctrl-k.  Or upload the photo to imgur and post link.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/paIgO.jpg

Comment: That picture does not help.  In your original post using edit. Copy some data and paste it in the original post.  Then highlight the data ans hit Ctl-k.  Then add the expected outcome in the original post.

Comment: 3157802 SP N
3157801 SP N
3157800 SP N
3157799 SP N
3157798 SP N
3157796 SP N
3157797 SP N
3157795 SP N
3157794 SP N
3157791 SP N
3157790 SP Y
3157789 SP N
3157787 SP N
3157788 SP Y
3157786 SP N
3157784 SP N
3157785 SP N
3157783 SP N
3157779 CB Y
3157782 D1 N

Comment: So now explain what your desired outcome is.

Comment: I need a true statement in a sense that the No after ''Y" be true so i can restrict that product but not all the ''No" should be true only 1 after the Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In K188 put:

```
=IF(AND(J187="Y",J188="N"),"Y","N")
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. It is working 210% correct. Thank you for you time and help much appreciated.

Comment: @SydneyMtsweni Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only the one who posed the question can do.